# CSS Columns that Overflow Below

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

In creating a multi-column, snaking layout, using CSS Columns, it seems content wants to naturally overflow to the right. I'm looking for a solution that will overflow below the fixed height of the parent container.

For example:

This is the natural flow when the content has reached the limit of the fixed height and overflows:

```
---------
|[1] [4]| [7]
|[2] [5]| [8]
|[3] [6]| [9]
---------
```

This is how I'd like for it to overflow:

```
---------
|[1] [4]|
|[2] [5]|
|[3] [6]|
---------
[7]
[8]
[9]
```

Example HTML

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 1
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 2
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 3
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 4
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 5
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 6
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 7
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 8
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 9
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 10
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 11
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 12
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 13
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 14
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 15
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 16
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 17
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 18
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 19
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 20
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        Test Item 21
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS

```
.page {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.column {
  column-count: 2;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  break-inside: avoid;
  break-before: always;
}
```

Here's a Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Nikolnikov/pen/yLJLpQp

Any suggestions? Is it even doable?

Comment: Please include your HTML and CSS in the question.

Comment: I included a Codepen example. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: No, thank you for asking; per the site rules, code has to be *in the question itself*. If and/or when the CodePen gets removed or CodePen itself goes down, the question becomes unanswerable due to lacking necessary detail. If it were an answer, then the answer would lose its usefulness for the same reason.

Comment: Exact effect is not possible, however there are some good practice for column handling in the Internet. If you want my answer about it - first I need to know what is the reason - responsiveness or weird idea of limiting space for content

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this result with flexbox and `flex-wrap` property. I think this example will help.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column > div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I have a string of data with a single parent container. I do not have the ability to wrap the blocks of data in extra divs. CSS Columns works great for this, until it needs to overflow. I'm looking for newspaper columns style solution.

It would be like your example above, but without the class="column" wrapping divs. Here's a Codepen example: https://codepen.io/Nikolnikov/pen/yLJLpQp